# close thread which is blocked while reading from inputStream

Tags: java, multithreading

here is code

```
private static class NgrokRunner implements Runnable {
    private InputStream inputStream;

    private boolean doStop = false;

    public NgrokRunner(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;

        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);

                if (keepRunning()) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("break ----");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Ngrok exception");
        }
    }

    public synchronized void doStop() {
        this.doStop = true;
    }

    private synchronized boolean keepRunning() {
        return this.doStop == false;
    }
}
```

and i started above thread like this

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    processBuilder.command("ngrok", "http","8080", "--log=stdout");

    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        NgrokRunner runner = new NgrokRunner(process.getInputStream());
        Thread ngrokThread = new Thread(runner);
        ngrokThread.start();                                            
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            Thread.sleep(10L * 100L);
        }
        //System.out.println("It works");
        runner.doStop();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO: handle exception                                                    System.out.println(e);
    }
```

But in while loop my child thread which is reading input from ngrok , blocking and even after calling `doStop()` it never reached at `if` condition where i am checking bool flag to exit from thread.

Well can anyone suggest me logic to achieve my ideal situation.

what i want is "Run ngrok server through binary file of ngrok in a thread and close the thread/ngrok whenever i want ( like when user wants through a pause/end button )"

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions (`catch (Exception e) { }`), this is a _very bad_ practice which will simply hide errors instead of resolving them, which just makes it impossible to find out why things don't work.

Comment: sorry what you mean ? I just started java :)

Comment: You should, at the very least, print out errors/exceptions when they happen: `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`. Catching generic exceptions is another matter I won't get into, just don't ignore errors.

Comment: ok i will, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i solved it and here is final solution

run() code :

```
@Override
public void run() {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        try {
            while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
                if (!reader.ready()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        continue; 
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        //TODO: handle exception
                        System.out.println("We got interrupted");
                        return;
                    }
                }

                line = reader.readLine();

                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Ngrok exception" + e);
        }
    }
```

Now from main thread

```
try {
       process = processBuilder.start();
       NgrokRunner runner = new NgrokRunner(process.getInputStream());
       ngrokThread = new Thread(runner);
       ngrokThread.start();

       for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
           System.out.println(i);
           Thread.sleep(1000);
       }
       ngrokThread.interrupt();
} catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e);
}
```